# Vim pymode: meaning of <C-c> key combination

Tags: vim, python-mode

I have come across the following key combinations(...i assume) in vim pymode documentation. `<C-c>, <C-C>, <C-X><C-O>, <C-P>/<C-N>`. How are they to be interpreted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<C-c>` and `<C-C>` both mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I'm sure you can infer how to type the others.

See `:help key-notation`.